# можно ли у телеграм бота сделать что то похожее на эмбиды(как в дискорде)

Tags: python, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут токен')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
это код
```

это сообщения эмбиды
[image]

Comment: Слова "эмбиды" не знаю.

Comment: Я и слова "дс" тоже не знаю

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy вот смотрите это эмбиды